# Three matrix equations on the same line. Why is there extra space in between the 2nd and 3rd and what is a good fix?

Tags: align

Why does this code result in there being some extra space in between the 2nd matrix equation and the 3rd?

```
\begin{align} 
A = \begin{bmatrix}
I_x(q_1) & I_y(q_1)\\
I_x(q_2) & I_y(q_2)\\
\vdots   & \vdots  \\
I_x(q_n) & I_y(q_n)
\end{bmatrix}
&
v = \begin{bmatrix}
V_x\\
V_y
\end{bmatrix}
&
b = \begin{bmatrix}
-I_t(q_1)\\
-I_t(q_2) \\
\vdots   \\
-I_t(q_n)
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
```

**Results in** :

[image: result]

**Instead of**:

[image: insteadOf]

Comment: this is unrelated to overleaf or to latex2.09 (which hasn't been distributed for 20 years)

Comment: the simplest fix here is simply not to use align, and use `\[  \]` and no `&` but does your real document have multiple lines that you want to align on the `&` (which would require a different answer)?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My bad, I'm not very familiar with latex, I roughly threw in a tag that seemed relevant.
As I'm pretty new to latex, I don't entirely know what you mean by align on the `&` . I will assume you mean allign horizontally?

I am trying to convert a document from word to latex, and in the original document these 3 equations are alligned horizontally as in the second picture in my post.

There is no equation that comes below this one if that is what you're reffering to?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have attempted that and that has solved my issue, thanks!

Could you make a simple post so I could credit you as the one who solved the question? Or is there a way to mark a comment as having solved it?

Comment: `&` is a column separator just as you have used internally inside the bmatrix, align is for mult-line expressions like chains of inequalities where you need to align each line on the operators. You only have one line here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a single line expression (even thogh it contains matrices) and there is therefore no alignment between lines possible so `align*` and the `&` alignment points are not needed.

Simply use `\[....\]`  and remove the`&`.